# How to specify svn url to access a repos on a Windows machine from a mac on a local network?

Tags: windows, macos, url, svn, share

I don't use mac very often and am trying to figure out what the correct URL is to connect to a repository shared from my windows machine.  I was thinking of something like file://\winMachine/svnrepo, but that's not working.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see how that would differ from normal ways of accessing network shared resources. The only issue here would be that OSX might not resolve NETBIOS names, so you might want to use the IP.

You should clone the repository through command line or GUI using the URL provided by the SVN Server, ex.: http://10.0.0.1:8080/svn/Project/

```
[yurieastwood@mbp ~]$ svn checkout --username yeastwood http://10.0.0.1:8080/svn/SampleProject/trunk/
Authentication realm: <http://10.0.0.1:8080> VisualSVN Server
Password for 'yeastwood': *********

A    trunk/SampleProject.XmlImporter
A    trunk/SampleProject.XmlImporter/SampleProject.XmlImporter.csproj
A    trunk/SampleProject.XmlImporter/JsonConvertTask.cs
A    trunk/SampleProject.XmlImporter/packages.config
A    trunk/SampleProject.XmlImporter/bin
A    trunk/SampleProject.XmlImporter/bin/Release
A    trunk/SampleProject.XmlImporter/bin/Debug
A    trunk/SampleProject.XmlImporter/bin/Debug/SampleProject.Framework.pdb
A    trunk/SampleProject.XmlImporter/bin/Debug/Autorun.mdf
A    trunk/SampleProject.XmlImporter/bin/Debug/Autorun_log.LDF
A    trunk/SampleProject.XmlImporter/bin/Debug/SampleProject.XmlImporter.pdb
A    trunk/SampleProject.XmlImporter/bin/Debug/SampleProject.Framework.dll
A    trunk/SampleProject.XmlImporter/bin/Debug/Newtonsoft.Json.dll
A    trunk/SampleProject.XmlImporter/bin/Debug/SampleProject.XmlImporter.dll
A    trunk/SampleProject.XmlImporter/bin/Debug/Newtonsoft.Json.xml

Checked out revision 7.
[yurieastwood@mbp ~]$
```

P.S.: If you want to access shared folders from Windows machines you should use the SMB protocol, ex.: smb://10.0.0.1, through Finder -> Go -> Connect to Servers.